# jQuery Validation with promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, promise

I'm using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) for a signup form and trying to check if an email address is already taken as part of the validation. The problem is that the check happens via a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), and I don't know how (or if) I can make this work with the validation plugin. Here's what I have currently:

```
$("#signup form").validate({
    rules: {
        emailSignup: {
            email: true,
            required: true,
            remote: checkAvailable
        }
    }
});

function checkAvailable() {
    var email = $("#emailSignup").val(),
        available;

    App.isEmailAvailable(email)
        .then(function(response) {
            available = response;
        })
        .error(function() {
            available = response;
        });

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (available == true) {
            console.log("is available");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("not available");
            return false;
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

The `setTimeout` is just a hacky way to ensure I have the response before I try to log it (I know that's terrible, but it's just for testing).

The thing is, this *will* correctly log `is available` or `not available` depending on the email address I enter, so it works up to that point. But I can't seem to actually return `true`/`false` back up to the `remote` method so that it kicks off the error handling. So what happens is anything that's a syntactically valid email gets marked as valid, even if it's logging `not available` based on the response.

Is this at all possible?

---

**Update**: I also tried doing this in a custom method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("email", function(value, element) {
    var field = this,
        available;

    App.isEmailAvailable(value)
        .then(function(response) {
            available = response;
        })
        .error(function() {
            available = response;
        });

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (available == true) {
            console.log("is available");
            return field.optional(element) || /^[\w-+\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/.test(value);
        } else {
            console.log("not available");
            return false;
        }
    }, 100);
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a valid email address."));
```

So the idea here is it would check if the address is available, and if it is, then it would check that it's syntactically valid. Again, it correctly logs `is available`/`not available` based on the address I enter, but doesn't return `true`/`false` properly to mark the field as valid or invalid.

Comment: You're using [the `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) all wrong.  The `remote` parameter should contain a URL to a server-side script... not another JavaScript function.

Comment: Right, but I have to use my `App.isEmailAvailable()...` promise to do the check. It could be this is completely not supported by the plugin, I was just hoping there was a way to make it work...

Comment: The `remote` method is doing `ajax` on a URL parameter.   By passing it a function instead of a URL, it's trying to access your JavaScript function via `ajax`, so obviously it will not work.  [Have you tried making a custom rule?](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)

Comment: There is no `this` when you have `element` which already represents the field.  What does your error console say?  Are your `console.log` lines working?  I suspect the timeout is not needed here.

Comment: The `var field = this` is so that I can call `return field.optional(element)` inside the `setTimeout()` without `this` referring to a different context. Anyway, the `console.log` lines are working correctly, I just can't get it to return `true`/`false` properly.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the "remote" jquery validate rule :

```
$.validator.addMethod('users_email_exists', function (value, element) {

    var method = 'remote';

    var previous = this.previousValue(element, method);
    var validator = this;

    if (!this.settings.messages[element.name]) {
        this.settings.messages[element.name] = {};
    }

    previous.originalMessage = previous.originalMessage || this.settings.messages[element.name][method];
    this.settings.messages[element.name][method] = previous.message;

    var optionDataString = $.param({data: value});
    if (previous.old === optionDataString) {
        return previous.valid;
    }
    previous.old = optionDataString;

    this.startRequest(element);

    new Promise(function (fulfill) {

        // YOUR STUFF, YOUR AJAX GET/POST REQUEST AND URL WITH PARAMS

        $.get('/backend/users/ajax/filtered-users-list', {email: value})
            .done(function (data) {


                    // YOUR STUFF TO VALIDATE DATA

                    // IF VALID TRUE -> validation success
                    // IF VALID FALSE -> validation failure


                var valid = !data.length;





                fulfill(valid);
            })
    }).then(function(valid) {

        validator.settings.messages[ element.name ][ method ] = previous.originalMessage;

        if ( valid ) {
            submitted = validator.formSubmitted;
            validator.resetInternals();
            validator.toHide = validator.errorsFor( element );
            validator.formSubmitted = submitted;
            validator.successList.push( element );
            validator.invalid[ element.name ] = false;
            validator.showErrors();
        } else {
            errors = {};
            message = validator.defaultMessage( element, { method: method, parameters: value } );


            // YOUR STUFF, YOUR VALIDATION MESSAGE HERE

            errors[ element.name ] = previous.message = 'EMAIL ALREADY ASSIGNED TO AN USER';



            validator.invalid[ element.name ] = true;
            validator.showErrors( errors );
            }
            previous.valid = valid;
            validator.stopRequest( element, valid );
        });

        return "pending";
    },
    "EMAIL ALREADY ASSIGNED TO AN USER"
);
```

Then call your custom rule :

```
$("#signup form").validate({
rules: {
    emailSignup: {
        email: true,
        required: true,
        users_email_exists: true
        }
    }
});
```

Include this script as Promise class reference :

```
<!-- promise -->
<script src="https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-7.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-done-7.0.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function that you've passed to setTimeout() will execute in future (a.k.a asynchronously) - after your checkAvailable() is completed. So its returning value is meaningless for the checkAvailable().

You should do rather the following:

```
DisableTheForm();

App.isEmailAvailable(value)
        .then(function(response) {
            $("#signup form").validate();
            if( it is valid) {
               EnableTheForm();
               PostFormData(); 
            }
        })
        .error(function() {
           CryAsItIsNotAvailable();
           EnableTheForm();
        });
```

So to do your validation in response of positive feedback of your isEmailAvailable

Comment: The `.validate()` method is only used for _initializing_ the plugin, so it should not be put inside of the promise.

Comment: Hm, that's clever...check if the address is available first, then trigger the validation rather than the other way around. That might be crazy enough to work ;-) I'll check it out...

Comment: `$("#signup form").valid()` then.

Comment: What triggers the promise?

Comment: promise callbacks get executed (fulfilled) by setTimeout or AJAX response callbacks.

Comment: I mean what triggers it within the context of the jQuery Validate plugin?  The OP is looking for integration.

Comment: Yeah we know.  However, the OP is trying to integrate jQuery Validate with his promise function.  He wants to trigger a validation error message based on the result of his promise function.  I'm asking you _how_ that would be done.  If you think it cannot be done, just say so.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `remote` method because it's looking for a URL parameter to access "*remotely*" via `ajax()`.

You obviously would not call a JavaScript function with `ajax()`, so using `remote` to call a JavaScript function makes no sense.

---

You might be able to create a custom function using [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).  However, you will have issues if any part of that is performed asynchronously as the custom rule will be evaluated before you have the result.

Comment: See my update – I basically tried exactly that, but I still can't get it to return `true`/`false` correctly.

Comment: @daGUY, the `addMethod()` method is pretty simple stuff, just using a `return true` or `return false` to properly trigger the message.  Are your `console.log` lines working?  Perhaps you don't need that timer.

Comment: Yep, the console lines work fine – I just can't get it to return `true`/`false` properly.

Comment: @daGUY, then it's a timing issue.  There's nothing incorrect about `return true` and  `return false`.

Comment: @Sparky Messier, you've missed the fact that functions in `then()` and `error()` are asynchronous.  `available = response;` will be executed *after* your `checkAvailable()` completion.

Comment: Without the timer, it always returns `false` because `available` doesn't have any value (since the response hasn't come back yet).

Comment: @daGUY, you've hit a wall then... or between a rock & hard place.  I know of no workaround.

Comment: @daGUY That's simply wrong. then() method in promises schedules passed function for later execution.

Comment: @daGUY, the spec seems clear... `promise` is `asynchronous` and deferred, so I don't see how you're going to be able to pull this off.  Why can't you just write a server-side script and access it using `remote`?

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was some way to do this, but I guess not. I'll look into alternatives. Thanks!